# How to add values from one dataframe into another ignoring the row indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, setting

I have a pandas dataframe called `trg_data` to collect data that I am producing in batches.  Each batch is produced by a sub-routine as a smaller dataframe `df` with the same number of columns but less rows and I want to insert the values from `df` into `trg_data` at a new row position each time.

However, when I use the following statement df is always inserted at the top. (i.e. rows 0 to len(df)).

```
trg_data.iloc[trg_pt:(trg_pt + len(df))] = df
```

I'm guessing but I think the reason may be that even though the slice indicates the desired rows, it is using the index in df to decide where to put the data.

As a test I found that I can insert an ndarray at the right position no problem:

```
trg_data.iloc[trg_pt:(trg_pt + len(df))] = np.ones(df.shape)
```

How do I get it to ignore the index in df and insert the data where I want it?  Or is there an entirely different way of achieving this?  At the end of the day I just want to create the dataframe trg_data and then save to file at the end.  I went down this route because there didn't seem to be a way of easily appending to an existing dataframe.

I've been working at this for over an hour and I can't figure out what to google to find the right answer!

Comment: Did you look here? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have the answer (I thought I had already tried this but apparently not):

```
trg_data.iloc[trg_pt:(trg_pt + len(df))] = df.values
```

Still, I'm open to other suggestions.  There's probably a better way to add data to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is save all the intermediate dataframes in an array, and then concatenate them together

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = []
# get all the intermediate dataframes somehow

# combine into one dataframe
trg_data = pd.concatenate(dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
trg_data = pd.concat([df1, df2, ... dfn], ignore_index=True)
```

and

```
trg_data = pd.DataFrame()    
for ...: #loop that generates df
    trg_data = trg_data.append(df, ignore_index=True) #you can reuse the name df
```

shoud work for you.